# jQuery Mobile : go to a new html page disable the transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a page with a navBar and a footer like the screenshot :

[image: f]

The code simplify of this page, which is the same for the pages agenda / people / info is :

```
    <div data-role="page" data-id="access-dataid" id="page-infos-access" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header" data-id="header-app" data-position="fixed">
            <div data-role="navbar" data-id="head-navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#page-infos-access" data-id="access-link" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" id="custom-header-nav-active">Access</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page-infos-contact" data-id="contact-link" data-transition="slide">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-id="f1" class="custom-tabbar-icon" data-position="fixed">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="agenda.html" id="agenda-icon" data-icon="custom">Agenda</a></li>
                    <li><a href="people.html" id="people-icon" data-icon="custom">People</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist"  id="infos-icon" data-icon="custom">Infos</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" data-id="contact-dataid" id="page-infos-contact" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header" data-id="header-app" data-position="fixed">
            <div class='ui-title'>
            <div data-role="navbar" data-id="head-navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#page-infos-access" data-id="access-link" id="custom-header-nav-active">Access</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page-infos-contact" data-id="contact-link" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" data-transition="slide">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-id="f1" class="custom-tabbar-icon" data-position="fixed">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="agenda.html" id="agenda-icon" data-icon="custom">Agenda</a></li>
                    <li><a href="people.html" id="people-icon" data-icon="custom">People</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist"  id="infos-icon" data-icon="custom">Infos</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Basically for the navBar menu I hide and show part of the html but I don't load a new page. Everything works fine, I can change from the navBar item "Access" to "Contact".

The problem is when I click at the bottom, and load a new page like "people.html", the navBar items which use exactly the same system don't work. I see the new page but when I click on the top item, nothing happen, like the JS bug...

Any idea ?

Comment: so _people.html_ contains more than `data-role=page` div?

Comment: Yes, people html has exaclty the same header and content, juste the link in the footer is a little different because the class ui-btn-active change from the old item selected to the new

Comment: If you load _people.html_ via HTTP `rel="external"` it will work, otherwise it will be loaded via Ajax and won't work. You cant mix between _single page_ and _mullti-page_ models in jQM. Its either single or multi.

Comment: Thanks a lot you find a solution for my problem ! It force to load the page, it not smooth because we see the reload but it works ! Can I do better in the architecture of my project ?

Comment: Because it's load normally via HTTP not Ajax, a brand new HTML file is loaded.

Comment: Ok I get it. I have a last problem, if I add my website to my home (on iPhone), when I click on a rel=external link, it launch safari (because it's external of course). There is no way to make it stay in the fullscreen website instead of launching safari ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47885/discussion-between-pull-and-omar)